# Is it acceptable to post general "What are your thoughts on this class/code?" questions?

Tags: discussion, design, feedback

Obviously there are times when a developer comes to the SO community because he/she's trying to work out a bug or a performance issue and simply wants help.

But suppose you have a class/method/whatever that you've written (the sort of thing that might go into a general-use library), and you're not actually experiencing any problems with it; it seems to work fine. You would just appreciate if others could take a look at it and provide general feedback: does it seem well designed, is the interface intuitive, is it implemented reasonably efficiently, etc.

Does this sort of question have its place on SO? Or is this not really in the spirit of the site's purpose as a Q&A resource?

Comment: I got away with this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/192980/boiler-plate-code-replacement-is-there-anything-bad-about-this-code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you ask a good solid (answerable) question about the code, then there is nothing wrong with doing that.

If your question is just waffle or vague, or along the lines of *"hey yous fellas what do you finkz about my codez"* then i don't think anyone is really interested.

Comment: Yeah, obviously your example is an exaggeration to be funny, but... I guess I feel like there's a gray area where the post might actually be articulately worded but still pretty much just amount to that: "What are your thoughts on this code?" So would you say, then, that a request for a general code review (which is really what this would be) is probably not reasonable?

Comment: I was exaggerating my answer, but you might be surprised how often it happens. I think it comes down to articulating what your concerns are with the code: *"do i have a possible memory leak here?"*, *"have i implemented pattern xyz properly?"*, *"pattern xyz is preventing me from doing what i really want to do, how do i get round that?"*, *"is there a better way to iterate this list looking for a specific value?"*.... etc....

Comment: Right. OK, that makes sense: if you're going to ask a question of this nature, just be sure to make it clear what specifically you are uncertain about.