# [meta-tag:advice] has issues

Tags: discussion, meta, burninate-request

**[advice](/questions/tagged/advice)** has 20 questions, no followers, no tag wiki, and no overarching purpose. It is mainly used where the asker is unsure of whether to do something, which I thought was implicit if a "should I" was posted.

Selected examples of meta-tag-ness:

- [Should I propose the new tag "rundeck"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/197016/should-i-propose-the-new-tag-rundeck)
  [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) [tags](/questions/tagged/tags) ***[advice](/questions/tagged/advice)***
- [Can I receive some account ban advice?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/189077/can-i-receive-some-account-ban-advice)
  [support](/questions/tagged/support) [accounts](/questions/tagged/accounts) [post-ban](/questions/tagged/post-ban) [ban](/questions/tagged/ban) ***[advice](/questions/tagged/advice)***
- [How should we treat anonymous edits that are useful but don't fit the normal rules?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147479/how-should-we-treat-anonymous-edits-that-are-useful-but-dont-fit-the-normal-rul)
  [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) [suggested-edits](/questions/tagged/suggested-edits) ***[advice](/questions/tagged/advice)***
- [Where can I ask questions about payment gateways or implementing billing myself?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78555/where-can-i-ask-questions-about-payment-gateways-or-implementing-billing-myself)
  [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) [asking-questions](/questions/tagged/asking-questions) [scope](/questions/tagged/scope) [site-recommendation](/questions/tagged/site-recommendation) ***[advice](/questions/tagged/advice)***

There are possible redeeming examples. Full list I've found:

- [How to address SO questions that are deemed "too vague", or seeking advice](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135716/how-to-address-so-questions-that-are-deemed-too-vague-or-seeking-advice)
  [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) [asking-questions](/questions/tagged/asking-questions) [policy](/questions/tagged/policy) ***[advice](/questions/tagged/advice)***
- [Should we provide tangential advice?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116718/should-we-provide-tangential-advice)
  [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) ***[advice](/questions/tagged/advice)***
- [Is it acceptable to post general "What are your thoughts on this class/code?" questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63852/is-it-acceptable-to-post-general-what-are-your-thoughts-on-this-class-code-qu)
  *borderline example*
  [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) [design](/questions/tagged/design) [feedback](/questions/tagged/feedback) ***[advice](/questions/tagged/advice)***
- [What advice would you give beginners joining a Stack Exchange site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61039/what-advice-would-you-give-beginners-joining-a-stack-exchange-site)
  [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) [stackexchange](/questions/tagged/stackexchange) [new-users](/questions/tagged/new-users) [help](/questions/tagged/help) ***[advice](/questions/tagged/advice)***

What to do?

Comment: nuke it, the nuke the remains

Comment: No meta-meta tags please.

Comment: @UV-D You must have some obsession with nuking stuff...

Comment: @davblayn that's what I get for playing Civ4

Answer (score 1):

The 2 redeeming posts you mention seem to suggest a tag is needed for posts asking to properly provide advice to users, assuming we can find more applicable questions that just the 2.

Maybe a new tag called [advising-users](/questions/tagged/advising-users) with [advice](/questions/tagged/advice) as a synonym.

And then it could get a proper wiki to explain what it us for

Comment: Found another two examples, but that's it AFAICT.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that the way [advice](/questions/tagged/advice) is currently used (*except* for some of your "redeeming examples", where it refers to advising users) is for requesting help (= advice) with the conventions and social norms on the SE network.  In that respect, it seems almost like a duplicate of [support](/questions/tagged/support), at least if one interprets the phrase "one of the site's features" in the latter tag's summary in a broad sense.

If this broad interpretation is the intended one, then I'd suggest:

1. editing the [support](/questions/tagged/support) tag wiki to make it clear that it also applies to requesting help with non-technical issues,
2. removing [advice](/questions/tagged/advice) from the few "redeeming examples" (and maybe retagging them with something like [advising-users](/questions/tagged/advising-users), as proposed by psubsee2003), and
3. making [advice](/questions/tagged/advice) a synonym for [support](/questions/tagged/support).